# Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined trying to create an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Created a discord bot that bans members I prefer responding with a message embed after banning someone but all I can do is a normal message I don't know why I can't create an embed even if I have discord.js up to date (v12)

the error i get:

```
(node:9604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\commands\ping.js:7:40)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\main.js:52:35)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Som3a12 RL\Desktop\Advanced coding\discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  description: "this is a ping cmd",
  execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Bots ping')
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setDescription(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. 
            API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`); 

    message.channel.send(embed)              
  }
}
```

Comment: You have two `Discord` variables and it seems you don't pass one to the `execute(message, args, Discord, client)` method. You should probably remove `Discord` from that list and use `execute(message, args, client)` but I'm not sure how you call `execute`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i did what you said but now i get a new error which is:
```const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                           ^

ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see in your error you are having also trouble in your main file with that code.

First of all you will ask for **discord.js** in your main code file (like index.js). Then in your command line as a see you set execute, so you need to go back in your main code file and set the command as :

```
  if (command === 'ping') {
            client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
}
```

We are heading once again back in command file and you set the code as :

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "this is a ping cmd",
execute(message, args, Discord, client){
             const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Bots ping')
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setDescription(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. 
            API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`); 

        message.channel.send(embed)              
    }
    }
```

And that should solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Discord defined, remove Discord from line 6 and try again

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
        ^

execute(message, args, Discord, client){
                         ^
```